# segmentation fault in llvm ir

Tags: segmentation-fault, llvm

I get seg fault error when memcpy is called (last line) in the following code. Can anyone guess why?

```
%gds0 = getelementptr i16* %ldcs0, i32 0
%gds0.i8 = bitcast i16* %gds0 to i8*
%gdd0 = getelementptr i16* %ldcs0, i32 0
%gdd0.i8 = bitcast i16* %gdd0 to i8*
call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i32(i8* %gdd0.i8, i8* %gds0.i8 ,i32 2, i32 4, i1 false)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what is the point of `getelementptr i16* %ldcs0, i32 0`? Those instructions don't do anything. And you use the same base address and same index twice, so your code is equivalent to

```
%ldcs.i8 = bitcast i16* %ldcs to i8*
call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i32(i8* %ldcs.i8, i8* %ldcs.i8 ,i32 2, i32 4, i1 false)
```

And having the source and destination pointers point to the same location is not allowed, as you can read [on the intrinsic's documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-memcpy-intrinsic):

> The '`llvm.memcpy.*`' intrinsics copy a block of memory from the source location to the destination location, **which are not allowed to overlap**.

So this could explain your error. Even if you fix it to use two different locations, though, it might still fail if:

1. Either the source or the destination memory are not owned by the process
2. Either the source or the destination memory are not aligned to 4 bytes, after you explicitly specified (in the argument list) that they are

Finally, you don't really need to use a `memcpy` for copying just two bytes, the above code could be rewritten by a `load i16*` followed by `store i16`.